# background-image doesn't appear with span class

Tags: html

```
<span class="arrow" style="width:20px;height:20px;background-image: url(image/arrow.png);display:inline-block;"></span>
```

However the arrow doesn't show up. I double checked the path. It's correct. What wrong am I doing?
I even tried display:block;
No change.

Comment: show your full path please, maybe background image size

Comment: Actual dimensions of the image:
1192x1192

Comment: http://localhost/report/image/arrow.png

That's the path.

Comment: maybe you could create an arrow use CSS only, without background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to triple check you path :)

```html
<span class="arrow" style="width:100px;height:50px;background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/50/cats/1/);display:inline-block;"></span>
```

For a cleaner code, you can write your CSS code outside of style attribute, in a separate file.

Comment: @vv123 sorry, can you add a screenshot of your file system maybe ?

Comment: I am emulating a server via XAMPP actually.

Comment: `image/verif` and `image/arrow` are not the same path

Comment: It's actually an old screenshot.
I want image/arrow.

Comment: Ok, your image is just too big, try to resize it to 20x20px with paint; Or add a `background-size:cover;` but not recommended

Comment: Ok That worked but this way doesn't work:

.arrow {background-image:url(image/arrow.png);display:inline-block;height:20px;width:20px;}

Comment: @vv123 this code is from another file or in a <style> tag ?

Comment: That's from a css file.

Comment: Figured it out! :)
Thanks. It was a problem with XAMPP.
However the problem was due to the image's size.